# How to deal with /fix massive exluded pages in google search console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Recently I noticed a sharp decline in users to my website. When I investigated this, I noticed this was caused by my google traffic. it has declined about 90%!
I opened up my Google Search Console and under "Coverage" noticed a huge amount of excluded pages (92,000 pages!).

I have two sites on one domain. One site is used like a blog( uses `Wordpress` and has `All in One SEO Pack` plugin), and the other one which is on a subdomain) is a Q&A site( uses `Question2Answer`).
In Google Search Console, under the domain name(i.e. mydomain.com), this is how it looks :

[image]

And when I chose the subdomain(i.e. qa.mydomain.com), this is how it looks :

[image]

Now, my host, had enabled `https`, for some time now, but since it was `AutoSSL`, I though maybe not going full `SSL` was the right decision and continued to use `http` as the default `URL` for both sites.
Until like two days ago, that I found out, this is wrong and adversely affects the `SEO`.
I went and enabled `SSL` rightaway on my Wordpress site using Simple `SSL` plugin and also changed the default URL on my Q&A site to use `https` and also added a two lines to `.htaccess` to redirect all `http` to `https`!
I also submitted the `sitemap` for my sites so it helps google to reindex them faster!

Something else that confused me even more, was that after activating `SSL`, I had to create new properties for them, so I did, and added the sitemaps for the new properties and not the old ones. I dont know if I should have also added the sitemap for the old properties that start with `http` or not!

I also noticed there are many weird `URL`s such as these that are nonsense! my language is not even Korean! its Farsi and I don't know if its just an error on google side that messed up the `Unicode`, or something fishy is going on! and actually responsible for the exclusion of pages :

[image]

I guess google mistakenly excluded my Q&A site contents to be a duplicate of my first site (since one was using `SSL` (google decided that my main site should use ssl!) and another one wasnt?!) and then removed all of the indexed pages from its search results!

I thought maybe activating the `SSL` will fix it but apparently I was/am wrong and neither of my sites have not yet recovered!

Previously when I posted an article it was instantly available on Google search results, but now, even after a full day, my new contents are not even indexed!

I have no clue what I should be doing to fix this for good and get all the excluded pages reindexed again!

Comment: You have ~62K pages excluded by the noindex tag - is that correct? This seems to be the bulk of the 92,000. Have you checked that your on-page canonical link uses https now? Have you made sure that all your absolute internal links use https rather than http too?

Comment: What do you mean by on-page canonical link using https? I forced all links to use https. I have not edited the links that I previously linked using http though!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller By the way why is this marked as duplicate? Would you be more precise on why you marked this as duplicate? clearly other questions couldn't solve my problem so I made an effort to create one that describes me problem clearly!

Comment: We have a catch all question for all questions related to search engines not indexing content.

Comment: I suspect that you moved the site to HTTPS but you have only the HTTP site validated in Google Search Console.  You should either add additional variants of your site or you should add a "domain property".

Comment: I added the domain property and the first picture shows the stats related to that! There are one property for each URL address, two for each site, with and without ssl!